# Automation of uploading files to CKAN

Tags: ckan

I would like to auatomatically upload files to CKAN using Python3. The following is from https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/filestore.html#filestore-api

Create a new resource and upload a file to it using the Python library requests:

```py
import requests
requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/action/resource_create',
              data={"package_id":"my_dataset"},
              headers={"X-CKAN-API-Key": "21a47217-6d7b-49c5-88f9-72ebd5a4d4bb"},
              files=[('upload', file('/path/to/file/to/upload.csv'))])
```

I would like to achieve this using Python 3. The (file keyword does not exist in Python 3). Do you need to use IP address of the server? I would like to use the regular URL.

### Update

Thanks for your reference to the request page. My code looks like this:

```
 import requests
    url = 'https://data.gov.au/api/3/action/resource_create'
    data={'package_id':'my_dataset'}
    files = ['upload',{'file': ('c:\python\xxopendata.xlsx', open('c:\python\xxopendata.xlsx', 'rb'))}]
    headers={'Authorization': '6cb2400e-9833-4946-9928-8c84cc451168'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=data,headers=headers,files=files)
    r.text
    print(r.text)
```

When I run this I get 'too many values to unpack'

Comment: I guess you will need to include the Content-Type in the headers. Thanks Zoran. but I still get the same error. I think it has to do with the files line. When I take the 'upload' out this error is gone but I need the upload keyword. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have provided is using requests library that works with Python3 and is not related to CKAN since you are using CKAN API to make an HTTP call. Please check the requests library and how you can send file https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file. The error you are getting is because in the last version file is renamed to files to upload a multipart-encoded file.

Comment: The OP has made an update to their post which they would like you to see (I have edited it in for them). If you would like to reply, please comment under the question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I would like a reply

Comment: I guess you will need to include the Content-Type in the headers.